# Rewriting RewriteRule to include back one particular php file in the path

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I inherited a large WordPress site: I was looking at the Wordfence live logs when I found users not loading a particular PHP page. I investigated and through an FTP client I found the file was where it was supposed to be. I used some network tool (in Chrome, Opera and Firefox) and, again, I found that file was returning a 404.

So, I found in the root of the website a short htaccess file containing this line:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/(.*)\.php$  [R=404,L]
```

I commented this out and reloaded the website: no error anymore. I must say, the error apparently doesn't cause anything strange to the website. But I would like to eliminate it.

I suppose this rule is meant to avoid someone can make a direct HTTP request to this and any other PHP file in that directory: in this case I suppose this file I'm talking about is called from an include, not directly, because in WordFence what I see is an error coming after a user accesses directly other pages, not this one in particular.

Anyway, I would like to rewrite this rule so that it stays the same as now, except for that php page. The PHP page is in the path of the theme:

*wp-content/themes/themeName/core/css/customized.css.php*

Is this possible? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exclude that specific php file from the `RewriteRule`, you can add a negative lookahead to the regex, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/(?!themes/.*/core/css/customized\.css\.php$)(.*)\.php$  [R=404,L]
```